# xCode not recognizong device & package

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to upload my first app into the Appstore. For that I need to configure my settings within xcode. I did everything like the handbook says but I a still getting 2 errors:

1. I have no Apple device so I tried launching the xCode Simulator to work as a device for me. That obviously didn't work. How can I fix this?
2. I used the name of my App-Bundle ID I created in the Appstore connect. Idk why this package does not get detected. Do I have to use sth else there?

[image: s]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to register at least one device on the apple developer account.

The second thing is you have to create provisioning profiles and certificates for your bundle id.
To have these provisioning profiles on your Xcode you need to login your Apple developer account on Xcode by following this link 
https://9to5mac.com/2016/03/27/how-to-create-free-apple-developer-account-sideload-apps/

Or this link:-

https://www.lynda.com/Unity-tutorials/Setting-up-your-iOS-Developer-account-Xcode/171054/182954-4.html

And for how to create provisioning profile you can follow this link:-

https://support.staffbase.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003598691-Creating-the-iOS-Provisioning-Profiles

To create certificates:-

https://learn.adafruit.com/introduction-to-ios-development/how-to-launch-your-app-on-your-ios-device

Or

https://customersupport.doubledutch.me/hc/en-us/articles/360001189514-iOS-How-to-Create-a-Distribution-Certificate

Answer (score 0):

You need to register at least one device in your account. Connect an iPhone and click try again.

Comment: I tried logging in with the simulator and connected it to my Apple ID. The problem is still occuring. Nothing changed

Comment: You need a real device.

Comment: I made it work by adding some dummy device IDs provided by apple